# Setting empty an array after onError

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Im workink on a webShop, some products has more than one color, so i recieve a diferente object with images about the products depending on color.
Im getting some wrongs image links from an api, so Im using onLoad to get all the good links i set them on an array. The problem is when I try to display another color object the array this.load does not reset, what it is doing is to add the new object into the this.onload array, and im getting an arry with 2 colors, and i need to swicht the color array.

```
loadedImg(e){
    this.setState({imgs: 0})
    console.log("null: ", this.state.imgs);

    var image = e.target.src
    this.loaded.push(image)
    this.loaded = _.uniq(this.loaded)
    this.size = _.uniq(this.size)
    this.setState({count: this.loaded.length, imgs: this.loaded})
    console.log('imgs: ', this.state.imgs);

  }
```

Comment: you need to set `this.loaded` to `[]` when you change the color. Show the relevant code that runs when you select a new color.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I dit set this.loaded = [ ] on
componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.loaded=[];
}
@GabrielePetrioli